# Should I consider parallelism in statistic callculations?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

we are going to implement software for various statistic analysis, in Java. The main concept is to get array of points on graph, then iterate thru it and find some results (like looking for longest rising sequence and various indicators).

**Problem**: lot of data

**Problem2**: must also work at client's PC, not only server (no specific server tuning possible)

**Partial solution**: do computation on background and let user stare at empty screen waiting for result :(

**Question**: Is there way how to increase performance of computation itself (lots of iterations) using parallelism? If so, please provide links to articles, samples, whatever usable here ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main point to use parallel processing is a presence of **large amount of data** or **large computations** that **can be performed without each other**. For example, you can count factorial of a 10000 with many threads by splitting it on parts 1..1000, 1001..2000, 2001..3000, etc., processing each part and then accumulating results with `*`. On the other hand, you cannot split the task of computing big Fibonacci number, since later ones depend on previous.

Same for large amounts of data. If you have collected array of points and want to find some concrete points (bigger then some constant, max of all) or just collect statistical information (sum of coordinates, number of occurrences), use parallel computations. If you need to collect "ongoing" information (longest rising sequence)... well, this is still possible, but much harder.

The difference between servers and client PCs is that client PCs doesn't have many cores, and **parallel computations on single core will only decrease performance, not increase**. So, do not create more threads than the number of user PC's cores is (same for computing clusters: do not split the task on more subtasks than the number of computers in cluster is).

**[Hadoop's MapReduce](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/)** allows you to create parallel computations efficiently. You can also search for more specific Java libraries which allow evaluating in parallel. For example, [Parallel Colt](http://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelcolt) implements high performance concurrent algorithms for work with big matrices, and there're lots of such libraries for many data representations.

Comment: Good point with "can be performed without each other". I'll certainlly keep that in mind.

Comment: Fibonacci has a closed form, allowing it to be computed in parallel. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio)

Comment: That's true, but almost all tasks may be parallelized with some mathematical transformation. The question is: how long will it take to find appropriate representation for the task to fit requirements. If it takes too long, in practice the task will be treated as non-parallelizable. That was my point.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Roman said, you should see whether the client's PC has multiple CPUs/CPU cores/hyperthreading. If there's just a single CPU with a single core and no hyperthreading, you won't benefit from parallelizing a computation. Otherwise, it depends on the nature of your computation.

If you are going to parallelize, make sure to use Java 1.5+ so that you can use the concurrency API. At runtime, determine the number of CPU cores like `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`. For most tasks, you will want to create a thread pool with that many threads like `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads)` and submit tasks to the Executor. In order to get more specific, you will have to provide information about your particular computation, as Roman suggested.

Comment: You could check for multiple processors and apply graceful degradation if your found only one core.

Comment: Xorty, the nice thing about dynamically checking the number of processors and creating a thread pool with that size is if a client happens to just have a single processor core, you will just be running one task at once, which is more efficient. Basically, your algorithm will dynamically adapt to the number of processors, as Willi suggested, without you having to do any extra work.

Comment: Ah, dind't see this brilliance before. Very nice indeed.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem you're going to solve is naturally parallelizable then there's a way to use multithreading to improve performance.

If there are many parts which should be computed serially (i.e. you can't compute the second part until the first part is computed) then multithreading isn't the way to go.

Describe the concrete problem and, maybe, we'll be able to provide you more help.